# go: type assert of interface

Tags: go, types

I have a problem with making dynamic model of a struct. I mean that I want to assert or cast, or just change the type of struct according to the incoming data strut.

if `sourceName` variable would be `type_x` , than the type of `deserializedData` should be `type_x`, if `type_y`, than `type_y`. How to set the variable `deserializedData` dynamicly for this ?

I have this part in my code:

```
    .... 



  var cacheData []byte
    var deserializedData models.NoaggModel

    cache_err := cache.Get(string(string(sourceName) + "_" + string(t.Date)), &cacheData);
            if cache_err != nil {
                fmt.Println("cache_error: ", cache_err)
                panic("the cache is empty")
            }

            err2 := json.Unmarshal([]byte(cacheData), &deserializedData)
            if err2 == nil {
                fmt.Println("deserialized data: " + string(sourceName), deserializedData)
            }

            for _, chart := range charts {
                w.Name = chart.Name

            if err2 == nil {

                w.Data = countDataByName(sourceName, deserializedData, t.Request.Filters, string(chart.Name))
            }
            out <- w
        }
....
```

How to modify it, to avoid setting `models.Noagg Model` type in a strict way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating an instance of a type dynamically during runtime can be done using the [reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package. You can use a map to store the different types that you should be able to create:

**Example:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
    Foo string
}

type Bar struct {
    Bar int
}

func main() {
    var sourceTypes = map[string]reflect.Type{
        "foo": reflect.TypeOf(Foo{}),
        "bar": reflect.TypeOf(Bar{}),
    }

    sourceName := "foo"
    var deserializedData interface{}

    deserializedData = reflect.New(sourceTypes[sourceName]).Interface()
    fmt.Printf("%#v", deserializedData)
}
```

**Output:**

> &main.Foo{Foo:""}

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/qeDA4cu5et

Comment: Thank you, i'd remember this type of switching

Comment: @Altenrion Welcome :) . Of course, you can use an ordinary switch too: `switch sourceName { case "foo": deserializedData = new(Foo) ... }` . Then you can avoid using `reflect`. Using a map is good if you want other packages to be able to add source types (eg. if you are writing a jsonrpc library). An ordinary switch is preferable if you have a limited and static set of types. Take your pick :)